# Flutter Provider The screen is not updating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have an app where I listen to its data coming in via bluetooth.

With the Notifier class, I can write the incoming data to the screen without any problems, and a new msg value is created by sending the incoming data to the setMsg method.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<BluetoothConnectionNotifier>(context, listen: true)
        .initBluetoothStream();

    return Consumer<BluetoothConnectionNotifier>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Text(value.msg)
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The problem is:

Although I print the incoming data to the screen, the value in Text() is not updated on the screen.

```
set setMsg(String value) {
    _msg = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }


void dataReceivedStream() {
    bluetoothConnection.input.listen((Uint8List data) {
      String dataString = ascii.decode(data);
      print('Received data: $dataString');

      int space = dataString.indexOf(' ') + 1;
      dataString.startsWith('N')
          ? setLedIsActive =
              dataString.substring(space, dataString.length).contains('1')
                  ? true
                  : false
          : setMsg = dataString;
    });
  }

void initBluetoothStream() {
    FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance
        .onStateChanged()
        .listen((BluetoothState event) {
      setBluetoothState = event;
    });

    _bluetoothState.isEnabled & isConnected()
        ? dataReceivedStream()
        : disposeMethod();
  }
```

It updates the msg value because it adds the ability to click anywhere on the screen and calls the setState method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround could be using an ValueListenableBuilder and wrapping your Text widget with it. This builder responds to changes in a ValueNotifier, rebuilding its children when the value changes.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<BluetoothConnectionNotifier>(context, listen: true)
        .initBluetoothStream();

    return Consumer<BluetoothConnectionNotifier>(
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: value.msgNotifier,
              builder: (context, String value, _) {
                return Text(value);
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

In your BluetoothConnectionNotifier:

```
ValueNotifier<String> msgNotifier = ValueNotifier<String>("");

set setMsg(String value) {
    _msg = value;
    msgNotifier.value = value;
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Now, each time you update msgNotifier.value, the ValueListenableBuilder will rebuild and your text will be updated on screen.

I assume you are using provider

Comment: Isn't the purpose of Consumer to detect changes and redraw them on the screen? I don't understand why we are using ValueListenableBuilder once again? Yes, i use Provider.